# should I use document.writeln?

Tags: javascript, document.write

Is the following javascript script problematic although it can load the desired result? Should `document.writeln` be replaced by `document.write` or even some other methods? I picked this idea up from the web http://www.wetlandpark.gov.hk/en/

```js
function getheaderHTML() {
  document.writeln('  <div id="nav">');
  document.writeln('    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>');
  document.writeln('  </div>');
  document.writeln('  <div id="header">');
  document.writeln('    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>');
  document.writeln('  </div>');
}

function getfooterHTML() {
  document.writeln('  <div id="footer">');
  document.writeln('    &#169;2016');
  document.writeln('  </div>');
}
getheaderHTML();
getfooterHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rajshekar Reddy.

Comment: Using `document.write` and `document.writeln` to append data to the page is considered bad practice.

Comment: Why can't you just write it as native html? Why do you need a script at all?!

Comment: Because if I want to change the layout of the webpages, I will only need to change the content of one file. Are there other alternatives to do this?

Comment: [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1529630)

Comment: Almost everyone says so but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no much difference between `write()` and `writeln()`. Only difference is `writeln()` adds a new line after each statement.

But for the above code having a new line or not doesn't make much of a difference as **white spaces are neglected in HTML**.

Also using `document.write` or `writeln` is not a good idea. I would suggest you to have 2 `div` which act as a placeholder for injecting your `header` and `footer` HTML.

I would only suggest to refactor your code to

```js
function getheaderHTML() {
  var content = '<div id="nav"><a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a> </div><div id="header"> <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260></div>';
  
  document.getElementById('pageheader').innerHTML = content;
}

function getfooterHTML(){
  var content = '<div id="footer">&#169;2016</div>';
  
  document.getElementById('pageFooter').innerHTML = content;
}

getheaderHTML();
getfooterHTML();
```

```html
<div id="pageheader">

</div>

<div id="BodyContainer">

</div>

<div id="pageFooter">

</div>
```

Comment: function getheaderHTML() {
  var content =  '  <div id="nav">'
                +'    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>'
  +'  </div>'
  +'  <div id="header">'
  +'    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>'
  +'  </div>';
  document.body.innerHTML = content;
}
function getfooterHTML() {
  var content =  '  <div id="footer">'
                +'    &#169;2016'
  +'  </div>'
  document.body.innerHTML = content;
}

Comment: It doesn't work. I mean the css formatting cannot be loaded.

Comment: **Never use `innerHTML +=`**. Especially on body.

Comment: @Oriol thanks for pointing it out.. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Sen I updated my answer to give you better standard approach. Please be updated.